# how to add data in cookie array without push into array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the object value to cookie array without push array to cookie. how can i do that ?i can use cookieDevObjArray.push(obj); but i want to push my object to cookie not whole array.How can i do that any help?
Here is object

```
 var obj =
 {
    'deviceid': deviceId,
    'full': cookiefull,
    'stacked': istoggle

 };

 $.cookie("cookieDevObjArray", + JSON.stringify(obj), { expires: 30 });
```

this code only save current object and override previous data.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the spread operator?

Comment: how can i use that ?

Comment: When you want to "merge" an object into an existing array as a new element of the array you can do ```newCookieObjArray = [...cookieObjArray,...obj]```. Just use it like this: ```...obj```

The ```spread``` operator only takes ```key:value``` pairs from an array instead of the whole array/object

Answer (score 1):

You should first get your specific cookie key then parse it and doing your operation then set the cookie again

```
 var obj =
 {
    'deviceid': deviceId,
    'full': cookiefull,
    'stacked': istoggle

 };

// First get your previous cookie
const array = JSON.parse($.cookie("cookieDevObjArray"))
array.push(obj)

// Setting new value
$.cookie("cookieDevObjArray", + JSON.stringify(array), { expires: 30 });
```

Comment: Need to consider case where no JSON array exists in that cookie also

Comment: I want to push only object not full array to new cookie. any help

Comment: @fazalabbas It is impossible as far as I know

Comment: in javasciprt we use document.cookie +=name="value" for adding new cookie add with existing but in jquery how can i do that?

Comment: @fazalabbas When you are using `+=` you are overwriting the variable again and does not make a difference with my method

Comment: @fazalabbas Also with pure JS it is impossible if you want to update just a part of a string that saved in the cookies , No matter Jquery or pure JS